# Is the google drive file id settable?

Tags: google-drive-api

Google drive SDK works with file ids.

When a new file is uploaded, the sdk returns a file id, i.e. it creates one.

Can this id be set by the caller either during the upload or after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are talking about a [file resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource) here.

If you check the documentation you will see that some fields are writeable while some like ID are not writeable.  You cant set the file id only Google can assign a file id.

**Update:**
You can use [Custom File Properties](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/properties) to add your own ids.

*update2:*

you can use [Files: generateIds](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/generateIds) to create an id used with files.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Now I have to redesign my app.

Comment: we use properties https://developers.google.com/drive/web/properties to add our own IDs

Comment: Updated answer @pinoyyid I need to try that.